# Unset value from array by value, not key

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
Array (
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 8)
```

I want to remove some items of the array but by value, not by key. How I can do that if I want to remove all the items with the value "4", or with the value "x"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`array_search`](http://php.net/array-keys)

```
$key = array_search(4, $arr);
unset($arr[$key]);
```

If occurences of value in array is more than once use [`array_keys`](http://php.net/array-keys):

```
$keys = array_keys($arr, 4);
foreach ($keys as $k)
    unset($arr[$k]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try it this way:

```
<?php

 $data = array('haha', 'hehe', 'hihi', 'gtfo', 'hoho', 'huhu');

 $data = preg_grep('/^(?!gtfo).*$/', $data);

 print_r($data);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => haha
    [1] => hehe
    [2] => hihi
    [4] => hoho
    [5] => huhu
)
```